# Loop the function for testimonials: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, loops

Can someone help me how will I loop this one to load again if it reaches the end. I've tried using `.promise()` and `.done()`.

but still I am having hard time to loop it, it crashes the browser.
Thanks in advance!

Here's my HTML Code:

```
<ul>
<li class="testi"><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image" />
    </li>
    <li class="testi"><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0f0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
    </li>
    <li class="testi"><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/00f/fff.png&text=my+image" />
    </li>
    <li class="testi"><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/ff0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
    </li>
    <li class="testi"><img src = "http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0ff/fff.png&text=my+image" />
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's my script:

```
function testi() {
 $(".testi").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(5000 * index).fadeIn(5000).fadeOut();
    });
}
testi();
```

Comment: how did you use promiose/done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```js
function testi() {
  $(".testi").hide().each(function(index) {
    $(this).delay(2000 * index).fadeIn(2000).fadeOut();
  }).promise().done(testi);
}
testi();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="testi">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x90/f00/fff.png&text=my+image" />
  </li>
  <li class="testi">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0f0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
  </li>
  <li class="testi">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x90/00f/fff.png&text=my+image" />
  </li>
  <li class="testi">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x90/ff0/fff.png&text=my+image" />
  </li>
  <li class="testi">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/120x90/0ff/fff.png&text=my+image" />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
function testi() {
 $(".testi").each(function(index) {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).delay(5000 * index).fadeIn(5000).fadeOut();
    });
   setInterval(testi, 5000);
}
```